# Backstage tech-docs configuration returning "Error: spawn mkdocs ENOENT"

Tags: backstage

When I try to run Backstage locally, and visiting the Project documentation, I'm getting the following error:

> error: Failed to build the docs page: Failed to generate docs from /tmp/backstage-5lZR3i into /tmp/techdocs-tmp-hvh4yi; caused by Error: spawn mkdocs ENOENT {"timestamp":"2022-06-02T18:02:06.573Z"}

[image]

Does anyone have a clue?

I'm trying to config my Backstage tech docs. I have an external Gitlab repo and I put the following files in the repo root directory:

**mkdocs.yml**

```yaml
site_name: ${{values.component_id}}
site_description: ${{values.description}}

nav:
  - Home: index.md

plugins:
  - techdocs-core
```

**docs/index.md**

```markdown
# example docs

This is a basic example of documentation.
```

In Backstage, my component yaml looks like this

**packages/catalog-model/components/my-site.yaml**

```yaml
apiVersion: backstage.io/v1alpha1
kind: Component
metadata:
  name: My-Site
  description: This is a component.
  annotations:
    argocd/app-name: 'my-site'
    gitlab.com/project-id: '007'
    backstage.io/view-url: https://some.website/catalog-info.yaml
    backstage.io/edit-url: https://git.my-company.net/my-company/backstage/blob/main/packages/catalog-model/components/my-site-component.yaml
    backstage.io/source-location: url:https://git.my-company.net/my-company/my-site
    backstage.io/techdocs-ref: url:https://git.my-company.net/my-company/my-site/
spec:
  type: component
  lifecycle: experimental
  owner: Dream
  system: Platform
```

Comment: Having the exact same issue... Were you able to fix it?

Comment: my answer seems to solve this issue. Can you please accept it?

Answer (score 3):

I think this error happens when `mkdocs` is not installed locally. You can refer to these [installation guidelines](https://www.mkdocs.org/user-guide/installation), and the issue should be solved

Answer (score 0):

Backstage suggest to modify the `Dockerfile` for solving this problem.

https://backstage.io/docs/features/techdocs/getting-started#disabling-docker-in-docker-situation-optional

```
# Dockerfile
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip
RUN pip3 install mkdocs-techdocs-core==1.0.1
```

**Edit**: This docker script should be into `packages/backend/Dockerfile`. Because the entire file generate running in the backend